# How can I emit from a seperate file with socketio? (flask)

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

#### How do I allow a separate file (in this case, `classes.py`) to emit socketio messages?

`classes.py` has know knowledge of the `socketio` variable, and even after trying to import it directly, it does not work.

Please help me solve my issue!

Here is my code;

***`app.py`***

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, send_from_directory, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from classes import *

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://localhost:6379')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    socketio.run(app, port=5000, debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

***`classes.py`***

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, redirect, url_for, jsonify
import requests, json, random, sqlite3
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

class notify:
    def __init__(self, message=None):
        socketio.emit('notification', {'message': message})
```

---

#### My current fix

- Send POST request internally to `@app.route()`, which triggers a `socketio.emit()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to have a circular reference.
You should divide `app` variable from the entry point.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, send_from_directory, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://localhost:6379')
```

classes.py

```
from app import socketio

class notify:
    def __init__(self, message=None):
        socketio.emit('notification', {'message': message})
```

main.py

```
from app import app, socketio
from classes import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    socketio.run(app, port=5000, debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Comment: Now that makes a whole lot more sense. Thank you very much

Comment: You're a goddamn lifesaver, I was struggling for hours, bashing my head in as to why it doesn't work as no errors, no output was present!